# sql fiddle code for foreign key and primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

I need help trying to figure out the code for these two tables. I am using  SQL Fiddle.

Oder Table

```
Donut Order ID (PK) INT (10)    
Customer ID(FK) INT (10)    
Order Date DATETIME (6)    
Special Notes VARCHAR (30)
```

Order Line Item Table

```
Donut Order ID (PK)(FK) INT (10)    
Donut ID (PK)(FK) INT (10)    
Qty INT (10)
```

I have my Customer Table and my Donut Table but I keep getting errors when I try to tables with foreign keys. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your sqlfiddle link? Along with what error you are getting.

Comment: CREATE TABLE OrderTable
(
  donutorderid varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  customerid varchar (10) NOT NULL,
  oderdate datetime (6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (donutorderid),
  FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES customer(customerid)
 );
Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Your Customer table schema? Also data you are trying to insert. And also if you are inserting data make sure that data exist in customer table before inserting in OrderTable

Comment: Sorry here's the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79365   That is for the Order Table, which works when I build the schema with the foreign key command. I have tried with the Alter Table command and with the foreign key command in the Create table statement.                         ALTER TABLE OrderTable ADD INDEX checks (customerid), ADD CONSTRAINT checks FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES Customer (customerid);

Comment: Please see the answer below .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your schema and there schema and it is working fine for me

Try this to create schema for OrderTable with foreign key reference

```
 CREATE TABLE `OrderTable` (
  `donutorderid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `customerid` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `oderdate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`donutorderid`),
    CONSTRAINT `ordertable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerid`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So there was a small error in your ALTER command

in Customer table the name of field is customer_id and not customerid.

Try this:-

```
ALTER TABLE OrderTable ADD INDEX checks (customerid), ADD CONSTRAINT checks FOREIGN KEY (customerid) REFERENCES Customer (customer_id);
```

SQLfiddle for same:- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0eb295

Comment: Oh wow thank you. It worked. I should be able to figure out the other one now. So you have to use customer_id at the end of the statement. I really appreciate it.